# Observable that notifies new subscribers of its current value

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to know what is currently (as of KO 3.1) the recommended way to implement/extend an observable that notifies **new subscribers** of its current value?

And yes I'm aware that I could just call observable.valueHasMutated but that is not the point of this question :-)

Comment: Why don't you just get the value when calling `subscribe`?

Comment: @GôTô Because I want to avoid repeating the same code path for the initial value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with an extender that will override the subscribe function to notify the subscriber:

```
ko.extenders.notifyOnSubscribe = function(obs) {
    obs.originalSubscribe = obs.subscribe;
    obs.subscribe = function (callback, target, ev) {
        callback(obs.peek());
        return obs.originalSubscribe(callback, target, ev);
    }
    return obs;
};
```

You can test it with the following **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/FE6Y9/)**